# Function call sequence

Tags: design

The question is related to software engineering best practice. If I have a function foo() that needs some non-trivial variables (say some 2D arrays) to be set before it can perform its action, is it better to have the caller set those variables and pass them on when it calls foo(), or is it better to write foo() such that it calls a third function bar() that sets the variables for foo(). The latter will result in a chain of function calls, possibly one for each input argument. Should I favor this over having everything set in the caller's scope before calling foo()?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: It's not much about what I tried that didn't meet my needs; I have a working implementation, but I want to write readable, and good code. I was just wondering which style would a professional programmer choose.

Comment: It depends - there is no general answer that is clearly better in all situations. If you only need those "non-trivial variables" within the function, it might be better to keep them local to the function - limit their scope to where they are needed. If their initialization may be changed independently of the function changing, however, then it will be better to define a clear interface for interacting with the data and inject it as an external dependency. As it stands, this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Context, Soheil. Different things might be better in different parts of the architecture, or even different scales. For this case in particular, start thinking about encapsulation. Also consider if there are side effects, and consider testing. Even concurrency, can you get the values async? Yet, in general, I would side with passing values as parameters. If you need to, you can then wrap that with a routine that calls the functions that gets the values and pass them as parameters. Are you worried about performance? Let the compiler worry. If testing shows it is a problem, you can refactor.

Comment: Many thanks Hulk and Theraot. You pretty much answered what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this highly depends on the context of your domain and the problems you are trying to solve, I think what you describe should certainly be avoided in most scenarios.

It sounds like you are describing something like the following:

```
int[] DataParameter;

void SetParameters(int[] data)
{
    DataParameter = data;
}

int SumData()
{
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (int x in DataParameter)
        sum += x;

    return sum;
}
```

This makes it possible to call `SumData` when `DataParameter` has not been initialized properly which is definitely a code smell. Instead, utilize function parameters:

```
int SumData(int[] data)
{
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (int x in data)
        sum += x;

    return sum;
}
```

This function is "pure" (takes only what it needs and uses only that data to calculate and return some result).

Let's say you have a large number of parameters (usually more than 3-5 depending on what kind of data it is). Surely this will be annoying to pass as a bunch of parameters? This is where you make a type (class/struct) for your parameters:

```
class DataParameters
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public int[] SomeData { get; set; }

    // etc.
}

int SomeFunction(DataParameters parameters)
{
    // use parameters to calculate some stuff and return a result
}
```

The general goal is that it should be as hard as possible to call your code in an incorrect/illegal way. If you go around writing a bunch of functions that will not work properly unless you call some other functions first, you'll generally be in for a bad time and lots of bugs. By starting with pure functions for your core functionality, you'll be sure that most of your code will be easily refactored and reused later on.

If there is some other aspect of this pattern you are concerned about, feel free to comment, and I'll do an edit to try and address it.